# `use-package` and `define-key`

Tags: key-bindings, use-package, multiple-cursors

I'm using `multiple-cursors`, setting it up with `use-package`. By default, when `multiple-cursors` mode is enabled, `<return>` is bound to `multiple-cursors-mode`. I'm trying to override that adding this after `:config` in the `use-package` declaration:

```
(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<return>") nil)
```

So, this is part of my `init.el`:

```
(use-package multiple-cursors
  :ensure t
  :bind (("s-d" . mc/mark-next-like-this)
         ("s-D" . mc/mark-all-dwim)
         ("s-L" . mc/edit-beginnings-of-lines)
         ("s-<mouse-1>" . mc/add-cursor-on-click))
  :config
  (define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<return>") nil)
    )
```

Unfortunately, when `multiple-cursors` mode is enabled, `C-h k` tells me

```
<return> runs the command multiple-cursors-mode (found in mc/keymap)
```

I tried putting the `:config` bit before `:bind` just in the off chance it had something to do with the way `:bind` works, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: 1. Can you try evaluating `(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<return>") nil)` after using mc. Is it unbound after? 2. Or by wrapping it inside `(with-eval-after-load 'multiple-cursors-core (define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<return>") nil))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the source code (of multiple-cursors) helped me with this one. :)

This key is defined in file `multiple-cursors-core.el` and the end of this file  `provides` the feature `multiple-cursors-core`, so you have to `use-package` this feature.

```
(use-package multiple-cursors-core
    :bind
   (:map mc/keymap
         ("<return>" . nil)))
```